# Stop typewriter animation and show full text in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, animation

I have the following code to animate the typewriter text in UITextView. 
The problem is after the animation starts from the beginning character by character, I want it able to show full text after a button is pressed.

What is the best way to show up the full text after animation starts?

```
var myText = Array("".characters)
var myCounter = 0
var timer:Timer?
var TextNumber = 0


func fireTimer(){


    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(Main1.typeLetter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func typeLetter(){
    if myCounter < myText.count {

        myTypeWriter.text = myTypeWriter.text! + String(myText[myCounter])
        let randomInterval = Double((arc4random_uniform(8)+1))/190
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: randomInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(Main1.typeLetter), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    } else {
        timer?.invalidate()

    }
    myCounter += 1


}

@IBAction func showFullText(){
 //What should i put here?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate the timer and just put the complete text in your text view?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, i.e invalidate the time and convert array into string and place this text

```
   @IBAction func showFullText(){

         timer?.invalidate()

         let strFromArray = myText.joinWithSeparator(" ") 
         //In Swift 3, joinWithSeparator becomes joined(separator:)

         myTypeWriter.text = strFromArray

        }
```